Mutt not sending messages
Running fetchmail and exim on newly installed Debian Bookworm. My ~/muttrc file follows"
set realname = "Haines Brown"
set from = "haines@histomat.net"
set use_from = yes
set editor = "nano"
set charset = "UTF-8"
my_hdr Bcc:haines@histomat.net
my_hdr X-Operating-System:`uname -o` `uname -r` Debian Bookworm
set edit_headers = yes
set record=~/.mutt/muttArchive
set copy=yes
set signature = /home/haines/.mutt/signature
my_hdr Bcc:haines@histomat.net


I send a test message: $ mutt -s "Test" haines@histomat.net
As this configuration above suggests, a copy is sent to ~/.mutt/muttArchive
but not to /var/mail/haines and despite the my_hdr Bcc: a copy is not sent
back to me.
Am I correct that a message sent from CLI in this way is independent of exim4? Or us exim4 configure the likely culprit? Sendmail is not installed.
